# Bootstrap and Glyphicons on Azure

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, azure, fonts

I have an app that I am trying to deploy as an Azure Website. This app uses Bootstrap. Everything works well, except for the glyphicons. For some reason, I get a bunch of 404 errors when I try to load the glyphicons. They work fine locally.

I have the five glyphicons-halflings files stored in `/pub/fonts`.

In my `BundleConfig.cs` file, I have:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/site")
  .Include("~/pub/css/site.css"))
```

My `site.css` file has:

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      src: url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
      src: url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
   }   

   .ok {
     font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
     content: "\e013";
     height:18px; width:18px;
     color:green;
   }
```

In my .cshtml file, I have:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/site")
<div class=".ok"></div>
```

The symbol does not appear. Instead, I see a box. When I look in the developer tools, I see a 404 error associated with trying to load the fonts. I see 404s for:

- /pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
- /pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
- /pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
- /pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
- /pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
- /pub/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

I thought it was mime type related. So, I added the following to my web.config file:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
  <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/ttf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

However, that did not fix it. I'm still getting 404s for the fonts. At the same time, I need to keep them located in the `/pub/fonts` directory. I'm not sure what is causing this or how to fix it. It works fine locally. It just doesn't work when I deploy it to Azure.

Comment: The `content` property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Won't work unless you use it as `.ok:before { ... }`. As for the 404, I'd double check the URI to make sure that it's correct.

Comment: If you are using MVC, could you try adding an ignoreRoute so MVC doesn't try to handle the request? routes.IgnoreRoute("pub/fonts/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET - I tried adding the ignoreRoute, but that did not work. I still see 404 errors in the browser console. Oddly, when I click the link in the console window, the font comes up just fine. So a 404 doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Is the website running under root or set up as a virtual application, meaning it is inside a "folder" such as www.mydomain.com/mysite ?

Comment: The problem was the build action on the fonts in my project.